# Bootstrap show unwanted outline on the bottom of dropdown link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link with a dropdown menu. Problem is that when I click on the link the dropdown opens but there is unwanted border line on the bottom of the link. When i hover on the dropdown link the unwanted bottm line hides. But whenever mouse out from the link the unwanted bottom line displays again.

#### Here is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu2" style="color: #333;"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-lg"></i> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-align-left"></i> Reorder Pages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### Demo is here:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably border, outline or underline.
 Try this:

```
a.dropdown-toggle {
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can try and see if there is only one border bottom tho and cancel it only in case you want to use other borderlines.

Answer (score 0):

In  a:toggle Class have Text Decoration . Remove the text decoration.

a:hover {

```
color: #23527c;
text-decoration: underline;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Now you have

```
.dropdown-toggle:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

just add

```
.dropdown-toggle:hover,
.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

in your css, it resolves issue!

[Jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/vp8Lttnp/)